# Visual studio code keeps highlighting a single letter, and then I have to spam a certain letter to make it stop and code again

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently did "convert indentation to tabs" and now VSCode keeps highlighting a letter whenever I click on a new script (or go back and forth between one) and I have to spam a certain letter to make it stop so I can code again.

[image]

If I press a number, it'll appear typing on the status bar. I have no idea how to make it stop it's really annoying.

I tried converting to spaces or disabling convert to tabs, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It was Vim extension problem. I uninstalled it.

Comment: Please accept your answer so that future visitors instantly know that it worked.